# C# Tesseract OCR Minor character errors

Tags: c#, ocr, tesseract

I am trying to get text from image with .NET Tesseract (5.2.0) package. My image is very simple three line text which contains one special character (= sign).

The problem: it is either the text is horribly wrong or some characters are interpreted wrong. Most of the solutions offers paid services but I don't want to pay anything since I am trying to prove that reading characters from specific image is doable.

What I've already tried:

With an uneducated guess I thought DefaultPageSegMode could be how Tesseract evaluates images so I changed DefaultPageSegMode variable. Most successful one is SparseText mode.

Sample code

```
 using (var engine = new TesseractEngine("C:\\Users\\Eren1\\source\\repos\\DeleteLater_ReadImage\\DeleteLater_ReadImage\\bin\\Debug\\net7.0\\tessdata", "eng", EngineMode.TesseractAndLstm))
{
    engine.DefaultPageSegMode = PageSegMode.SparseText;

    using (var img = Pix.LoadFromFile("C:\\Users\\Eren1\\source\\repos\\DeleteLater_ReadImage\\DeleteLater_ReadImage\\bin\\Debug\\net7.0\\test9.png"))
    using (var page = engine.Process(img))
    {
        var text = page.GetText();

        using (var iter = page.GetIterator())
        {
            iter.Begin();
            string text2 = iter.GetText(PageIteratorLevel.Block);
            iter.Next(PageIteratorLevel.Block);
        }

        // text variable contains a string with all words found
        return text;
    }
}
```

The output:

```
005

1FH13=8

2005060

e N

(o) (o) — |
```

For example; =8 should be =S and 005 should be 2005

Sample image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTagN.jpg

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Improving threshold result for Tesseract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52992237/improving-threshold-result-for-tesseract)

Comment: Hi, Tesseract OCR needs you to further manipulate the image so the text becomes visible to the engine. You can try to negate the image, save the output to a file and then use that to create a new Pix object

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help. They said they have a free OCR API.

https://ocr.space/

Answer (score 0):

It's quite difficult to check what the problem is, especially without knowing your `tessdata`. Of course `Tessaract OCR` can indeed make recognition errors. your image seems to be of sufficient quality for OCR but I still would suggest trying to do some image preprocessing to improve the recognition quality - for example, increase the resolution or convert the image to black and white:

```
engine.DefaultPageSegMode = PageSegMode.SparseText;

// Preprocess the image
using var img = Pix.LoadFromFile(imagePath);
var scaledImage = img.Scale(2.0, 2.0); 
var grayImage = scaledImage.ConvertRGBToGray(); 

using var page = engine.Process(thresholdedImage);
var text = page.GetText();
Console.WriteLine(text);
```

Also it can be helpful to perform thresholding:

```
using var img = Pix.LoadFromFile(imagePath);

// Preprocess the image
var scaledImage = img.Scale(2, 2); 
var grayImage = scaledImage.ConvertRGBToGray();  
var thresholdedPix = grayImage.BinarizeOtsuAdaptiveThreshold(16, 16, 0, 0, 1.0f);

using var page = engine.Process(thresholdedPix);
var text = page.GetText();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in a project I had where I needed to recognize sections on an image with text. The images had text but Tesseract OCR was returning an empty text string. To fix this problem I used a class called built into Emgu CV called Tesseract. The full name of the library is

```
using Emgu.CV.OCR;
```

From my experience in Image Processing, Emgu CV OCR returns the most accurate results for most of the images I have encountered. This library also does not need you to further edit the image to enhance the recognition quality of the Tesseract OCR engine. To use this library in your project then install `Emgu.CV.runtime` nuget package and then use the code below to recognize the text on the image.

```
//define the data path
var tessPath = "C:\\Users\\Eren1\\source\\repos\\DeleteLater_ReadImage\\DeleteLater_ReadImage\\bin\\Debug\\net7.0\\tessdata";
//create a new instance of Emgu CV Tesseract Engine
var tesseract = new Emgu.CV.OCR.Tesseract(tessPath, "eng", OcrEngineMode.Default);
//define the image to scan for text
var mat = new Mat("C:\\Users\\Eren1\\source\\repos\\DeleteLater_ReadImage\\DeleteLater_ReadImage\\bin\\Debug\\net7.0\\test9.png");
//point the engine to the image
tesseract.SetImage(mat);
//recognize text
tesseract.Recognize();
//get the text
if(tesseract.GetUTF8Text()!=string.Empty){
   MessageBox.Show(tesseract.GetUTF8Text());
}
```